# Difference between $G$-module homomorphisms and $G$-linear maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

What is the difference between a $G$-module homomorphism and a $G$-linear map?  My understanding is that both are linear maps between vector spaces (say, from $V$ to $W$) and both preserve the action of the group $G$ (i.e., for all $g$ in $G$, $\rho(g*v)=g*\rho(v)$ for all $v$ in $V$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No difference, just different words.